# "Unexpected whitespace character" undefined "?"

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

ember-cli build issue. I have added "-W100":true inside global jshint file.
 I can't fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling `broccoli-es3-safe-recast` using

```
var app = new EmberApp({
    es3Safe: false
});
```

in `Brocfile.js`, as suggested [here](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/1397) should work.

Comment: Actually, after upgrading to ember-cli 0.1.2, this solution no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by the javascript file being encoded in UTF-8 with a BOM (byte order mark).

To fix it, I did the following:

1. Open the file in Notepad++
2. Click on the 'Encoding' menu
3. Click on 'Encode in UTF-8 without BOM'
4. Save the file